# How can this regex let a line like "0.0083" pass? grep -ioE '([0-9]{1,3}.){3}[0-9]{1,3}'

Tags: regex

I am trying to make a bash script for active scan of a network. It seems I don't have a hang on regex. The code looks like this:

```
#! /bin/bash                                                               
cd /home/pi/int_lib

for word in $(nmap -sn 192.168.1.0/24 | grep -ioE '([0-9]{1,3}.){3}[0-9]{1,3}' |
grep -v -)
do
    mac=$(arp $word | grep -ioE '([A-Fa-f0-9]{2}:){5}[A-Fa-f0-9]{2}')
    echo $word: $mac
done
```

I just want to know how it is possible that a line like "0.0083" can pass the first regex. nmap gives the response time for each host, and in exactly one case the mentioned line pass the filter. Why?

Comment: Not an answer, but [check this out](https://regex101.com/r/fA4gZ5/1). It's the regex at regex101. If you check the right pane it explains the regex in detail.

Comment: And... `.` matches any character. I believe you meant `\.` which matches dot.

Comment: And the answer would be - It can't. That regex could never match `0.0083`.

Comment: And ClasG - as i forgot to mention... The site you linked to is just gold! Thank you so much! :)))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The regex

```
([0-9]{1,3}.){3}[0-9]{1,3}
```

matches 1-3 digits followed by any character, 3 times, followed by 1-3 digits. That sums up to at least 7 characters/digits. Illustrated with `n` as digits, it can look like this

```
n.n.n.n
```

where `.` is any character, up to its longest form

```
nnn.nnn.nnn.nnn
```

Since `0.0083` only is 6 characters long, it can **never** match that regex.

**But**... simply adding a digit, e.g. `0.00831` makes it match.

Finally, I believe what you're after is the same, but with the `.` escaped, thus only matching dot.

```
([0-9]{1,3}\.){3}[0-9]{1,3}
```